# How to pair question answer from two list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two list which containing list of words and another list is label of respective words.
Now need to find the question answer pair from the two list. If we got list of questions and respective list of answers then we can zip. My mind is blind for this not getting how to do this.

Can some one please help me on this.

```
labels = ['header', 'header', 'header', 'header', 'header', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'header', 'header', 'header', 'header', 'header', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'header', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'answer', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'answer', 'question', 'question', 'answer', 'answer', 'question', 'question', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'header', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'answer', 'answer', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'answer', 'question', 'answer', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'answer', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'question', 'answer', 'answer', 'question', 'answer', 'question', 'question', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'other']

words = ['a', 'UK', 'Visas', '&', 'Immigration', 'ANNI', '|', 'Standard', 'Document', 'checklist', 'This', 'checklist', 'shows:', '©', 'the', 'Length', 'and', 'type', 'of', 'visa', 'you', 'have', 'applied', 'for', '‘©', 'the', 'documents', 'you', 'are', 'providing', 'in', 'support', 'of', 'your', 'application', '‘©', 'what', 'you', 'need', 'to', 'do', 'next', '‘You', 'must', 'only', 'sign', 'this', 'checklist', 'when', 'you', 'go', 'to', 'your', 'appointment,', '‘Your', 'appointment', 'is', 'at', 'New', 'Delhi,', 'on', '18', 'April,', '2018', 'at', '4:45', 'PM.', 'Mezzanine', 'Floor,', 'Baba', 'Kadak', 'Singh', 'Marg.,', 'Shivali', 'Stadium', 'Metro', 'Station,', 'Connaught', 'Place,', 'New', 'Dethi,', '110001,', 'INDIA', '‘Your', 'Prime', 'Time', 'appointment', 'must', 'be', 'pald', 'for', 'before', 'you', 'attend', 'your', 'appointment.', 'You', 'can', 'do', 'this', 'on', 'our', 'visa', 'application', 'centre', "partner's", 'website', 'at:', 'https:/iwww.visglobal.co.uk/globaV/index.html.', 'Product', 'Category', 'Visitor', 'visa', 'Duration', 'month', 'Payment', 'notification', 'number:', '3070005116926', 'Total', 'fee:', '8923.00', 'INR', 'Application', 'date:', '13', 'April', '2018', 'Applicant', "Applicant's", 'full', 'name', 'Sahil', 'Sareen', 'Date', 'of', 'birth:', '29', 'August', '1983', 'Country', 'of', 'birth:', 'India', 'Nationality', 'India', 'Passport', '/', 'Travel', 'document', '3859145', 'number.', 'Contact', 'telephone', 'number:', '+0091', '9873990024', 'Email', 'sahil.sareen21@yahoo.com', 'Submitted', 'date:', '18', 'April', '2018', '07:29', 'British', '‘Summer', 'Time', '(BST)', 'Gwro47660499', 'Sahil', 'Sareen', 'Page', '|', 'of', '8']
```

Expected output.

```
{'Category Visitor visa Duration': 'month',
 'Payment notification number': '3070005116926',
 'Total fee': '8923.00 INR',
 'Application date': '13 April 2018',
 "Applicant's full name": 'Sahil Sareen',
 'Date of birth': '29 August 1983',
 'Country of birth': 'India',
 'Nationality': 'India',
 'Passport / Travel document': '3859145',
 'number. Contact telephone number': '+0091 9873990024',
 'Email': 'sahil.sareen21@yahoo.com',
 'Submitted date': '18 April 2018 07:29 British ‘Summer Time (BST)'}
```

For more reference please check the image[image]

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: I think you may need to hardcode the values in to the dictionary.

Comment: No need to hardcode, split it into multiple steps: To go through two lists simultaneously use zip. Now you know which word has what label (header/question/answer/other) - with that you gotta merge all same-label stuff that is next to each other so you get phrases instead of just separate words. Then you'd go through the resulting list and pair each question+answer that are next to each other and put them in a dictionary.

Comment: Hai @h4z3 Thanks for the response. Have you tried through code. I tried the process which you explained but that is not matching with my expected output.

Comment: @Laxmi Just finished writing my explanation. I hope the step-by-step approach I tried to show helps you understand the code. I tried to write it in more beginner-style code rather than advanced pythonist magic.

Comment: Thanks a lot @h4z3 for your solution. I was struggling last 10 days now it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment: split it into multiple steps:

- To go through two lists simultaneously use zip. Now you know which word has what label (header/question/answer/other)...
- ...with that you gotta merge all same-label stuff that is next to each other so you get phrases instead of just separate words.
- Then you'd go through the resulting list and pair each question+answer that are next to each other and put them in a dictionary.

Note: your classification is wrong for "Visitor visa", so that merging will do "Category Visitor visa Duration" a one big-ass question... but your expected output actually also says that, so you're aware.

Let's start:

```py
for word, label in zip(words, labels):
    print(word, label)
```

We paired each word to its label.

Now, change the code to merge matching words that are next to each other. Smart way to do that would be using itertools.groupby. Manually it would be something like...

```py
tmp_phrases = []
tmp_labels = []
last_label = ""
for word, label in zip(words, labels):
    if label != last_label:
        last_label = label
        tmp_labels.append(label)
        tmp_phrases.append(word)
    else:
        tmp_phrases[-1] = tmp_phrases[-1] + " " + word
```

It's not really pythonic/elegant code, but should be easy to understand - I kept the structure of two lists (ugly) and just looked at when label changes. If label is not the same, I add another space+word to current last phrase.

After that, we can check how the phrases and their labels look:

```py
for phrase, label in zip(tmp_phrases, tmp_labels):
    print(phrase, label)
```

As I said above, because of wrong classification of "Visitor visa", in this step you'll see that `Category Visitor visa Duration` is a big-ass question.

Now, let's modify that last loop and put each q+a in a dictionary. To skip the top long stuff classified as questions and answers, let's only look at q and a that are next to each other. Also in more beginner-friendly way instead of magical pythonic way:

```py
result = {}
last_question = ""
for phrase, label in zip(tmp_phrases, tmp_labels):
    if label == "question":
        last_question = phrase.rstrip(":") # cleanup of hanging colons
    elif last_question and label == "answer": # non-empty question
        result[last_question] = phrase
    else:
        last_question = "" # reset q to empty to skip the misclassified top paragraphs

print(result)
```

Comment: Yes I know the "Category" has to question and "Visitor visa" has to answer and this two is wrong classification from the model.